# Set a different icon pack for gnome shell

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool

Is there any way to set a different icon pack for the gnome shell ?.

Currently, I can use the Ubuntu tweak tool to set the global icon theme and the icon pack gets applied for the shell as well as the GTK+. I would like to apply an icon pack only for the shell ( specifically for the panel )  and use the one selected in the tweak tool for global.

Following is my environment:

- Ubuntu Gnome 16.04
- Gnome shell 3.20.4

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible to set different icon packs for different components of the Gnome Shell desktop. The whole desktop environment relies on a single icon theme. In principle, what you want to achieve could be realized by substituting  relevant icons by versions you want.